# Why user's rights has that impact on my Views pages?

Tags: views, 8, entities

I have two custom entities (Adhérents and Personnes) linked to each other and to User.

- One 'Adhérent' is mainly a "family" and has these fields: label, adresse (postal address), Téléphone (landline phone number), date d'adhésion (Membership start date).
- One 'Personne' is a "person" ;-)  and has these fields: Nom (Lastname), Prénom (Firstname), Portable (Cellphone number).

Each 'Personne' is linked to one 'Adhérent'. One 'Adhérent' may be linked to many 'Personne' (one of these 'Personne' being the 'contact').  Each 'Personne' is linked to one 'User'.

'Personne' is defined as entity_reference for 'Adhérent' (as the 'Contact'):

```
$fields['contactid'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('entity_reference')  
  ->setLabel(t('Contact'))  
  ->setSetting('target_type', 'association_personne')
```

'Adhérent' is defined as entity_reference for 'Personne':

```
$fields['adherentid'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('entity_reference')
  ->setLabel(t('Adhérent'))
  ->setSetting('target_type', 'association_adherent')
```

'User' is defined as entity_reference for 'Personne':

```
$fields['userid'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('entity_reference')
  ->setLabel(t('Utilisateur'))
  ->setRequired(TRUE)
  ->setSetting('target_type', 'user')
```

I use Views to publish all these contents (see Screen captures below).

When I look at the output with a user with no specific rights (i.e. not Administrator), some of the data are not displayed:

1. In the 'Adhérents' view, the Contact column is empty (see capture 2) while there is a link to the entity (see capture 1).
2. In the 'Personnes' view, the link to the entity_reference 'Adhérents' is there but the link to 'User' that should display email address (see capture 3) is completely absent, the column header is not even there (see capture 4).

Any idea?

[image: Capture1]

[image: Capture3]

[image: Capture2]

[image: Capture4]

The Permissions as they are set:

[image: Permission1]

[image: Permission2]

Comment: I mostly toggle the "Disable SQL Rewrite" option when I create views because I prefer using the views access plugins rather than creating interfaces that behave differently for different users. Subjectivity aside, you may find this option under Advanced -> Query settings.

Comment: I just tried. Unfortunately, with no (visible) effect :-(

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand your problem correctly but would say that if it works as planned for admin user then the issue is with permissions.

Check permissions like: view user profile, view [entity type] etc.

Comment: Correct, being able to see entities and have them being linked depends on permissions defined by the given entity type.

Comment: I took care about that (see Permissions screen captures I added to my question).
What I don't understand is that it work in one way: 'Adhérent' as entity_reference is shown in 'Personne' Views page (captures 3 and 4).
But not in the other way: 'Personne' as entity_reference in 'Adhérent' Views page is shown when I look at it as Administrator (capture 1) but not when I am a 'normal' user (capture 2)...

Comment: And you've cleared all caches? Rebuild permissions? Logout and login?

Comment: Yes. Yes. Yes. And tried with different browsers as well...

Comment: And what is the purpose of email and contact column/link? If it takes to contact form then have you checked permissions to use contact form?

Comment: The Contact column in the 'Adhérent' view links to the standard canonical display (in order to show the information related to the person).  Then, I assumed that 'View Adhérent entities' permission would be sufficient.
The Email column in 'Personne' view allows to simply launch the user's mailing software to send an email...  Here, again, I thought that 'View user information' permission would be enough. It seems it is not the case :-( 
All this stuff is used to manage a non profit organisation where members interact thru the web site of the organisation.